# save a submitted form and then use a print modal at once

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that I submit using a bootstrap button, I have a modal that I link to in order to print using another button.  I want the printer button to save the form like the submit button does, but instead of redirecting to another page, it should redirect to the print modal (So the print contents are up to date).

This is my code I have that submits/prints currently.  If I make changes to a loaded form, the print button will only print the prior form.

```
<!-- Save Project -->
<div class='form-group text-center'>
    <input data-loading-text="Saving Project..." type="submit" name="invoice_btn" value="Save Project" class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-btm" />
    <!-- Print Project -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:500px; top:200px;"><a title="Print Invoice" class="print_class" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-uuid="<?php echo isset($invoice['Invoice']['uuid']) ? nl2br( $invoice['Invoice']['uuid'] ): ''; ?>" href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-print fa-4x"></i><br>Print</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Modal Print :

```
<!-- Modal Print -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:900px;height:auto">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Print Proposal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="print_content">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="printBtn" onclick="printInvoice('print_content')" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Printing...">Print</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @KalpeshSingh Printing goes off the uuid of a saved form.  It will not print current information updated within the form page, until it is saved.  I want the print button to save the form first, then print it(still based on its uuid)